# Bootstrap 4 data-* attributes not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I've updated Bootstrap 3.3.5 to Bootstrap v4.5.3 And jQuery 1.11.3 to jQuery v3.5.1 for my script. Everything was ok before, but after updates getting some problem in popover that I've use to show/hide column in datatable. Here is the code:

```
$instanceWrapper.find(".column-show-hide-popover").popover({
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        var tableColumns = "";
        $.each(settings.columns, function (index, column) {
            if (column.visible !== false) {
                var tableColumn = table.column(index),
                        columnHiddenClass = "";
                if (!tableColumn.visible()) {
                    columnHiddenClass = "active";
                }
                tableColumns += "<li class='" + columnHiddenClass + " list-group-item clickable toggle-table-column' data-column='" + index + "'>" + column.title + "</li>"
            }
        });
        return "<ul class='list-group' data-table='" + tableId + "'>" + tableColumns + "</ul>";
    }
});
```

It's working and show popover also, BUT when i checked there is no html Data Attributes (data-colum, data-table) in the output. It's return only Html Attributes like class, id etc. But not return any Data Attributes.

Can anyone help me to find the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you checking the `data` attribute? with `attrribute('data-table')` or `data('table')`?

Comment: @Sysix Please look closely my Code Snippet, It's not about the how I'm checking the data attribute. I've declared data attribute like normal html attribute.

Comment: @Sysix I beg to differ, your question states "BUT when i checked there is no html Data Attributes (data-colum, data-table) in the output". What output? How did you check? We've nothing to go on other than what you've said. As such this question is likely unanswerable without more details or a working example that exhibits the stated behaviour.

Comment: output means that 'return', and it's definitely Returns HTML, like <ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item clickable toggle-table-column">Title</li></ul> but Data Attributes are missing.